# How to transfer the image data uploaded using jquery to php?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a code here

```
  <h2>Click blue button</h2>
  <button id="open_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Open dialog</button>
  <div id="output"></div>

  <script src="src/bootstrap.fd.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#open_btn").click(function() {
      $.FileDialog({multiple: true}).on('files.bs.filedialog', function(ev) {
        var files = ev.files;
        var text  = "";
        files.forEach(function(f) {
          text += f.name + "<br/>";
        });
        $("#output").html(text);
      }).on('cancel.bs.filedialog', function(ev) {
        $("#output").html("Cancelled!");
      });
    });
  </script>
```

its a drag and drop upload using jquery and boostrap layout from http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Drag-Drop-File-Upload-Dialog-with-jQuery-Bootstrap. Its working, but the problem is, I don't know how to pass the data uploaded to php for processing and put the file into the server.

Anyone can help me with this?

Comment: have you tried anything to pass the uploaded data.

Comment: have u tried using ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try using ajax. Setup ajax in your project from tons of tutorials available on the net.
After that in your javascript function i suppose you want to pass variable `text` to php. So here's what you can do when you get a little hang about ajax by going through the tutorials

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#open_btn").click(function() {
          $.FileDialog({multiple: true}).on('files.bs.filedialog', function(ev)                {
            var files = ev.files;
            var text  = "";
            files.forEach(function(f) {
              text += f.name + "<br/>";
    });    
    $.ajax({
                url: "'your php function name'?name ="+text,
                success: function( data ) {
                    if(data == "retn value") { //return value of the php function
    //                  alert("");

                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
            $("#output").html(text);
          }).on('cancel.bs.filedialog', function(ev) {
            $("#output").html("Cancelled!");
          });
        });
      </script>
```

create a function in php which will take your data as an argument.
hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I try some tutorials with ajax